# Placing Images in loop in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I'm trying to place a set of images in a horizontal row in Tkinter. I do this by looping over a list, and loading the corresponding images from the working directory.
I place the images according to the index multiplied with a certain amount of spacing. However, when i actually place the images, they all get placed on top of each other in the last spot, instead of spaced out. The count value works fine, and when i `print(spacing*(count+1))` it outputs the correct values but when placing they all get bunched up in the last place.

Does this have something to do with the `Label()` class?

```
for count, mood in enumerate(mood_options):
    mood_img = Image.open(f"img/{mood}.png")
    mood_img_copy = mood_img.resize(img_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    mood_img_resized = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mood_img_copy)
    mood_img_label = Label(root, image=mood_img_resized).place(relx=spacing*(count+1), rely=0.35)
    print(spacing * (count + 1))
```

EDIT: I have used this exact method for placing buttons, see below:

```
for count, mood in enumerate(mood_options):
    mood_btn = Button(root, text=mood.capitalize(), command=lambda mood=mood: register_mood(mood), width=7) \
        .place(relx=(count + 1) * spacing, rely=0.5)
```

This works flawlessly, which makes me wonder why it wouldn't work with images, instead of buttons.

Comment: I would suggest that you use either `.pack` or `.grid` to make the placement easier since you wouldn't need to calculate anything and `Label` is a class not a function

Comment: Throughout the whole project i'm using `.place`, and combining that with either `.pack` or `.grid` would not work.

Comment: first of why are you using `.place`? second, pack and either one of the other layout managers can be used simultaneously in the same container

Comment: I thought i would have more control over the exact placement using `.place`. With `.pack`, you only have control in left, bottom, etc. as far as i know. And using `.pack` when placing iteratively seems a bit strange when comparing it to `.place` as the exact position can be chosen.

Comment: You can also use `.grid` which has more control than pack but iteratively it certainly is easier to use `.pack` because it will automatically stack the things wherever needed (I mean yes left right top bottom but usually that is enough), otherwise you can use `.grid` which allows to configure row and column, also usually you don't need an exact pixel perfect placement in a GUI, it would be hard to adjust it if the window is resized and other stuff, for example here you use the `x` coordinates, in `.grid` you could just use `column=count` and that's it, if using pack then specify `side='right'`

Comment: But i'm using the `relx` parameter in `.place` for consistent positions when the window is resized, which places the image as a 'fraction' of the window size.

Comment: It's NOT anything to do with the images being "bunched up", it's simply due to the fact that all of your images other than the last one were garbage-collected and ceased to exist.  You have to hold a reference to a `PhotoImage` object for its entire desired lifetime - but you are overwriting `mood_img_resized` on each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the same logic works for buttons,  then the problem might be the image is garbage collected, in this case you cannot store the image as an attribute of some class to hold reference, because over each iteration each image will be overwritten, holding refence to the last image only. Same happens with `global` as well. So the way to go here would be appending to a list. Try something like:

```
lst = []
for count, mood in enumerate(mood_options):
    mood_img = Image.open(f"img/{mood}.png")
    mood_img_copy = mood_img.resize(img_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    mood_img_resized = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mood_img_copy)
    lst.append(mood_img_resized)
    Label(root, image=mood_img_resized).place(relx=spacing*(count+1), rely=0.35)
    print(spacing * (count + 1))
```

Though it would be much better to place stuff using `grid` to place it in a grid like manner. If your worried about responsiveness of the window then look at `weight`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mood_options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for count, mood in enumerate(mood_options):
    Label(root, text=mood).grid(row=0,column=count,padx=50)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(count,weight=1)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Kinda pointless to assign the return value of layout managers to a variable

Comment: @Matiiss Good catch, I was just copy pasting code from the original code, edited

Comment: Why does appending to a list cause the `mood_img_resized` to not be overwritten?

Comment: @Laurens Because you are storing each of the image in a list, and none of it is being neglected or overwritten, there is a reference to each image in the list

Comment: That clears it up, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your `spacing` the actual amount of space in pixels?
If so, leave away the `relx` and only use `x`. `relx` has to be a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I'm using `relx` to preserve relative position when the window is rescaled. The thing is that i have used the exact same method for placing buttons (with relx, spacing, count etc.) which works, but somehow for images, or labels doesn't work.

Comment: Well I just checked, and your method also works for Labels (with text only, no images):

`from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
mood_options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
spacing = 0.25


for count, mood in enumerate(mood_options):
    mood_img_label = Label(root, text=mood).place(relx=spacing*(count+1), rely=0.35)
    print(spacing * (count + 1))

root.mainloop()`

Comment: Yes, that's why i find it confusing. I works with buttons (as i have done before) and labels, but not with a label with an image in it. It is just the case that it is not possible like this or am i just doing it wrong?